# How is REST stateless?

Tags: rest, soap

I know REST and knows to create RESTful web services without using session, i know its better but I don't really understand the concept of stateless and how using REST can make your application scalable

Can someone explain these two aspects of REST, stateless and scalability and how is SOAP different and not advisable?

Answer (score 6):

A stateful API would maintain sessions for all connected clients. This would mean that the sessions need to be shared between servers, which limits scalability.

By storing this state on the client and sending it with each request, you can have the same state, but with better scalability.

Comment: so, if i understand, for scalability to be a point, there must be several servers, if there is only one, then there is only one session store/user, am i right?

Comment: Even then, sessions need to be shared within one server, which always has *some* performance impact. It's a good habit to design your APIs to be stateless. It also makes it easier for those who want to interface with the API.

Answer (score 2):

Creating RESTful services doesn't make your application scalable, you *can*, in fact, create RESTful services which are session based and can't live across multiple machines, or sticky session, or completely stateless.

As for scalability, many factors determine whether or not a service is scalable, and in fact a service *can be* scalable even if it requires a session (for example if your service has sticky sessions meaning that a session is hosted on one machine and the web visitor always comes back to the same machine where his session lives).

Stateless services make scaling out easier because it means that once a request has been processed, the next request from that web visitor does not necessarily have to come back to the same machine, which means you can (in theory) have as many machines as you want service the same kind of requests.  If your traffic doubles in volume you just add the same number of machines and boom, you can now service twice as many requests.

In practice, however, things get complicated, and it is rarely possible to create completely stateless services.  Most times, if your web visitors can update data, you have concurrency issues as two web visitors can change the same data and some kind of synchronization has to happen to prevent data corruption.  In those cases, you might want to split your service so that the services that let you change data are NOT stateless, and those that let you extract data are.  In most cases I would guess that most of the heavy lifting is in the data extraction side rather than data update, so this works out fine.

As for SOAP, I can only say that the world is moving towards REST as it is more light-weight.

Answer (score 1):

Being stateless means that you can have as many front as you want, each of them can answer a request the same way, there is no filesystem session to take care of i.e.

So you can scale (adding as many front as you wish), this is the most obvious reason to go stateless.

Comment: Being stateless is the most obvious reason to be stateless? I think you will either add a few words, change a few words or remove a few words...

Comment: I've worked with web services where each and every request will have an XML file containing a username and password and you need to put it each and everytime, so in this case, this would also be scalable

Comment: @madflow rewritten this part.